# I want to have a simple jquery slider for my plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am using appendTo and prependTo function but what happens if there are two sliders on same page the content of second slider gets appended to first slider as i m takin class and classes are same for both the sliders . I can generate dynamic ids for both sliders ..but i m finding it difficult to get those ids in javascript .. Heres my demos

[My Gallery Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/vaibviad/t2n52/1/)

This will show u my div structure and also javascript code ...

```
$('.imageslider > img.arrow.left').click(function(e) {
   e.preventDefault;
   var rotator = $(this).parents("div").find('.images');
   //alert("asdasd"); 
   rotator
      .children('.imageHolder.' +    navigation)
      .last()
      .prependTo(rotator)
      .removeAttr("style")
      .css("margin-left", "0px")
      .animate({marginLeft: "0px"});
});
```

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/each/

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use two slider in span and then assign class to span
eg for slider 1

.class1 .slider{}

for slider 2
.class2 .slider{}
 it might work

Comment: didnt get u @avinash ..can u plz explain in detail